# Capturing HTTP responses in cucumber tests to use in a different step definition

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am writing integration tests using cucumber for a HTTP service in Java. What I was interested in is to make a HTTP request in one of the step definitions and assess the response of this request in another step definition.

Is there any provision in cucumber to return something in a step definition and use that data in another step definition (may not be the immediate next step). Or are there any other libraries that could help me achieve this? Or may be any other ideas to achieve this?

I did think of keeping the response in step definition instance variable but that would become bit annoying with multi-threaded tests and I do not wish to write thread safety code for this thing.

Why I might want to do this is to keep the assertions in the order they happened. The steps following the request are to check the DB/Kafka topics the request had mutated. So I want to assess the response at the end. It is not a big deal but I would find it more verbose to write steps where the response is asserted at the end.

Comment: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer

Answer (score 0):

In Cucumber you can share things between steps. you cannot share things betweeen scenarios. Each scenario is meant to be an isolated independent test. The way you should be testing api calls that change things is exactly the same as any other Cuke. You use Givens to setup state, a When to make the call that changes something and Thens to examine the result of the changes.

Its perfectly OK to make several http requests to setup up your state, and return responses you use in subsequent calls until you get enough information to make the call in your When.

There is absolutely no need to break this pattern to test any api.